# GRUB error 17 booting USB disk

Tags: grub-legacy

I have a USB disk with Grub 1 installed.  I have 6 different Linux versions, all on different partitions, and one boot partition to hold the kernel images and grub.

On some systems this works great, I get the boot menu and I can pick the linux distro.  But on 2 systems I keep getting error 17 (and nothing else onscreen).

I've confirmed the partition table ordering is correct, the partition table is valid, no errors on boot partition, etc.  I've also reinstalled GRUB onto the MBR several times.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and what I can do to fix?

Answer (score 0):

What I've noticed is that some BIOS releases designate USB sticks as disks and initialize them after harddrives in the same system. This causes your grub config to look for the partitions on the wrong drive.

I would recommend trying syslinux instead, it is much more capable of running on removable storage.

Here's a link explaining how to use syslinux for this purpose:
https://superuser.com/questions/584625/multiboot-on-usb-with-syslinux

I'm afraid I don't have a solution for fixing grub though, sorry.